Why is a WPF UserControl's host window not considered its logical parent?
I was reading Rohit Vats' answer to this post after running into this problem myself & was wondering why the "parent" window of a UserControl is not considered its logical parent. He goes on to explain the resolution behavior but that's not the problem at all. The problem is that in a pretty obvious hierarchy of elements, for some reason, controls that would intuitively be considered children apparently aren't in WPF.

Because "logical parent" has no place in the discussion. One can say that at the top of the visual tree there is a WIndow; and that's about it. The UC itself could be "10 levels deep" in the tree. Is it still a "child" or is it a great-great-etc.

The window is the logical ancestor of all elements included in its logical tree.
This is easy enough to check:
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.CyrilCommando.question79128735.CheckAncestorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.CyrilCommando.question79128735"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="CheckAncestorWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Point x:Key="point">200 100</Point>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <UserControl>
            <Button Content="Find point" Click="OnFind"/>
        </UserControl>
    </Grid>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
        private void OnFind(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement? curr = (Button)sender;
            while(curr is not null && curr is not Window)
            {
                curr = curr.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            }
            string message = curr is null
                ? "Window not found"
                : $"Window found. Point = {curr.Resources["point"]}" ;
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
            ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Window>

I think your more precise question should be: "Why doesn't the StaticResource markup extension in a UserControl find the resources of the window where this UserControl is used?"
The thing is that StaticResource is determined (resolved) at the moment when it initializes the property. For a UserControl, this coincides with the call to the InitializeComponent(); method in Code Behind. This method is called in the constructor. But at this time, the UserControl instance has not yet been added to the Window and, therefore, the Window is not yet its parent.
If you use DynamicResource for example, it will be able to find the resources from the parent window without any problems. Because it determines the resources dynamically and re-searches them whenever the visual tree changes. So after adding the UserControl to the Window, DynamicResource will start searching for the resource again and will be able to find it in the Window's resources.
<UserControl x:Class="Core2024.SO.CyrilCommando.question79128735.SomeUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.CyrilCommando.question79128735"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <Button Content="Find point" Click="OnFind"/>
        <!--<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource point}"/> Error -->
        <TextBlock Tag="{DynamicResource point}" Text="{Binding Tag.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
        private void OnFind(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement? curr = (Button)sender;
            while(curr is not null && curr is not Window)
            {
                curr = curr.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            }
            string message = curr is null
                ? "Window not found"
                : $"Window found. Point = {curr.Resources["point"]}" ;
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
            ]]>
    </x:Code>
</UserControl>

